# 'view more' button won't work using classlist.add()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want this function to open a button of 'view more' and close it but there is something wrong with classlist.add tried several ways but without a solution been working on the code for several hours it's my first time trying to write a big code and it's tiring big respect to you guys.

the JS:

```
const modalViews = document.querySelectorAll(' .services__modal'),
modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(' .services__button'),
modalClose = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal = function (modalClick) {
    modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns.forEach((modalBtn, i) => {
    modalBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal(i)
    })
})

modalClose.forEach((modalClose) => {
    modalClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modalViews.forEach((modalView) => {
            modalView.classList.remove('active-mdoal')
        })
    })
})
```

the HTML code is long but I'll include it :

Experience
    I've worked with a range of technologies in the IT world. from
        web development to SharePoint administrator RPA
        technology

```
<div class="services__container container grid">

    <!-- SERVICES 1 -->
    <div class="services__content">
        <div>
            <i class="uil uil-grid services__icon"></i>
            <h3 class="services__title">Ui /Ux <br> Designer</h3>
        </div>

        <span class="button button--flex button--small button--link services__button">
            View More
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
        </span>

        <div class="services__modal">
            <div class="services__modal-content">
                <h4 class="services__modal--title">Ui/Ux <br>Designer </h4>
                <i class="uil uil-times services__modal-close"></i>

                <ul class="serivces__modal-services grid">
                    <li class="services__modal-secrives">
                        <i class="uil uil-check-circle serivces__modal-icon"></i>
                        <p>Lead the technical team and support SEC
                            end-to-end, from discovering great
                            automation opportunities everywhere to
                            quickly building
                            high-performing robots to managing
                            thousands of automated workflows.</p>

                    </li>
                    <li class="services__modal-secrives">
                        <i class="uil uil-check-circle serivces__modal-icon"></i>
                        <p>Work in UiPath environment as an RPA
                            Infrastructure engineer.</p>

                    </li>
                    <li class="services__modal-secrives">
                        <i class="uil uil-check-circle serivces__modal-icon"></i>
                        <p>Working in UiPath environment, as Business
                            Analyst and RPA Developer</p>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the CSS:

```
  .services__container {
   gap: 1.5rem;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.services__content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 3.5rem 0.5rem 1.25rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 00.3s;
}

.services__content:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.services__icon {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
}
.services__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.services__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}

.services__button:hover .button__icon {
  transform: translateX(0.25rem);
}

.services__modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  z-index: var(--z-modal);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3rem;
}

.services__modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.services__modal-services {
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.services__modal-services {
   display: flex;
}

.services__modal-title {
   font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.services__modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
 right: 1rem;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.services__modal-icon {
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-right: var(--mb-0-25);
}
 Active Modal 
.active-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing with? Can you add a reproducible code snippet rather than just the javascript code?

Comment: can you add also your HTML and CSS?

Comment: If this is your actual code, there are a few small problems that can easily be fixed, so here are some pointers:  in your css you have the text Active Modal before your intended selector `.active-modal` this will make the actual selector `Active Modal .active-modal` so the styling will apply to elements that contain the class 'active-modal' only if they are within a `<Modal>` inside a `<Active>`. my advice would be to remove the tekst 'Active Modal' from the css file.  another tip would be to check for typo's, I see 'secrives' and 'serivces' in your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I think your error is in the JS:

```
const modalViews = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
      modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.services__button'),
      modalClose = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal = function(modalClick){
    modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns.forEach((mb, i) =>{
     mb.addEventListener('click', () =>{
     modal(i)
     })
})

modalClose.forEach((mc) =>{
    mc.addEventListener('click', () =>{
       modalViews.forEach((mv) =>{
           mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
       })
    })
})
```